# How to save data persistend so I can use them offline

Tags: java, android

So I have one question, I have to do a chat application in school, with a feature which allows me to see my old conversations offline like in WhatsApp.

It kind of works after I turn immediately internet off and when I start then my app I can see my conversations, but after some time the chats are not loading anymore. I searched a bit on the internet and have read I have to save the chat as a file to the internal storage, but how do I do it I couldn't find anything about that.

This is my code for loading my messages online and offline

```
public void loadConversations() {
        boolean result;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileInput("CONVERSATIONS");
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            this.conversations = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<Message>>) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
            result = true;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }

        if (this.conversations == null) {
            this.conversations = new HashMap<>();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "loadConversations result: " + result + " size: " + this.conversations.size());

    }

    public void persistConversations() {

        boolean result;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("CONVERSATIONS",getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(this.conversations);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            result = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "persistConversations result: " + result);
    }
```

maybe someone can give me an pointer.

Comment: Using files is a bad way to solve your problem, you should use an relational database instead. I recommend you to use Room: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html

Comment: is there no way to do it with file? I have to be finished by tommorow, I read a bit about room but couldnt really implement it with my project

Answer (score 0):

There is the best way to make a chat app with firebase real-time database and when a user is offline (No internet connection). Firebase created a local database and store all the details in local and show your user-details and your messages. You don't need to create a separate database. Follow this link to know about firebase realtime database :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMInMag3qiV4wIVAh4rCh2fJQWAEAAYASABEgIfFPD_BwE

Comment: Sadly this did not work too, in a few hours I have to upload the project, is there no way to save it as a file?

Comment: I am using firebase real-time database for the android chat app and when the user is offline then all the messages before I sent that are retrieved automatically and set in my recycle view.

Comment: problem is our university does not give us complete permission we are using there servers. So I can not even implementing the database. It looks like I really have to save it in a file. Do you have any idea how to do that? I mean  it already is saving the chats but just after a few hours its deleting them

Comment: according to your situation, you have to create a local database and store your messages in the local database as well as in your school database.

Comment: without a real-time database, you can not create a chat app